# Start ssh-agent on login with multiple identities

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, ssh-agent

I have multiple ssh rsa keys on my computer that I use. That led me to having a file located at `~/.ssh/config` that looks like this:

```
#Bit Bucket Account
Host bitbucketid
 HostName bitbucket.org
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucketid

# Server
Host serverid
 HostName website.name
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/serverid
```

Here is what this links says to add:

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

function start_agent {
    echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add;
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

After following the advice from question [Start ssh-agent on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login), I can load the ssh key upon opening my terminal like so:

```
Initialising new SSH agent...
succeeded
Identity added: /Users/pc/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/pc/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

How can I automatically add the identity of one of my other rsa keys such as `serverid` or `bitbucketid`upon terminal starting?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I add these keys when the shell gets started. For instance if you were using bash, I would ssh-add the keys I wanted in my .bashrc file.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you would add them? I don't understand what you mean and putting `ssh-add ~/.ssh/serverid` into my .bashrc file does nothing

Comment: Doing ssh-add should work as long as the ssh agent has started. I do this at the end of my bashrc. I'll try to find a link.

Comment: This is similar to what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985927/set-ssh-identities-in-bashrc please post any errors you get. Also watch out for the gotcha where argument to ssh add is blank.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-add` takes the keys to add as parameters.

To add everything (that also have a publickey) you can replace this line  `/usr/bin/ssh-add;` with:

```bash
for f in "$HOME/.ssh/"*.pub; do
    ssh-add "${f%.pub}";
done
```

This loops through all the public keys, strips off the .pub extension and adds those keys to the agent.

It might get several random password prompts when opening a shell, which is why I'm using a version without the `ssh-add`... (If you are using encrypted public keys - you should)

The semi-colons at the end of lines are optional if formatted like this